# Vertex disjoint simple paths of length k

Tags: ds.algorithms, parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable

A lot of effort has been invested in finding simple k-paths, as well as in finding vertex disjoint paths.

Is there any known parametrized algorithm that given a graph $G=(V,E)$, decides whether there exist $p$ vertex disjoint simple paths of length $k$ in the graph?

Finding a single simple k-path is [known to be](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/col5.pdf) single exponent $FPT$ for a long time, what about this variant (with respect to both $p,k$ as parameters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this problem (or a generalization of it) was considered with the [Divide and Color](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/205/chp%253A10.1007%252F11917496_6.pdf?auth66=1394304624_4356f85023e9c4dd6d0926ee3f9365f8&ext=.pdf) approach yielding a $O^*(4^{(k-1)\cdot p})$ run-time algorithm for deciding the problem.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.
Using their $graph-packing$ algorithm, you can search for $p$ vertex disjoint copies of the graph $H=P_k$ in time $O^*(4^{(k-1)\cdot p})$.

If **both** $p$ and $k$ are parameters, this is a valid FPT algorithm (which is allowed to run in $O(f(p,k)\cdot poly(n))$.

What do you mean by "they will fall in different categories"?

Comment: Indeed, every path has to be of length $k$, not just a collection of $p$ disjoint paths with total length $k$.

I still don't see the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right I made a mistake, In your problem you don't have specific set of source and terminals, so this is correct.